# Testing Market Place app before deployment

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

My company has an application related to workflow automation and we need to deploy it on Google Market place for work. But before making it live or (other customers can view/download it) we need to test our application on a market place. I need to ask if there is a way to test application before deployment or any sandbox testing environment available?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing your app in the Chrome Developer Dashboard you can publish to your test accounts. Your app will be visible only for those accounts. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#step9) you can find more info on that.